# calculate centorid of the polygon kml

Tags: geometry, polygon, kml, computational-geometry

How to calculate centre of polygon when points are distributed unevenly ? 
In below `kml` file 30% of `lat/lons` are on one side hence average does not produce a good result. Does any one knows any good libraries to achieve it ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 
http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd 
http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2 
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd">
  <Document id="DLS_Parcels">
    <name>DLS_Parcels</name>
   <Snippet/>
<Folder id="FeatureLayer0">
  <name>DLS_Parcels</name>
  <Snippet/>
  <Placemark id="ID_00000">
    <name>189</name>
    <Snippet/>
    <description><![CDATA[<html><body><table border="1"><tr><th>Field Name</th><th>Field Value</th></tr><tr><td>OBJECTID</td><td>240106</td></tr><tr><td>SBPI_ID_NO</td><td>1076078</td></tr><tr><td>District Code</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>Municipality/Community Code</td><td>343</td></tr><tr><td>Quarter Code</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Block Code</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Parcel Number</td><td>189</td></tr><tr><td>Sheet</td><td>26</td></tr><tr><td>Plan</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>SRC_SL_CODE</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>SOURCE</td><td>DCDB</td></tr><tr><td>Parcel Area</td><td>2516</td></tr><tr><td>CadastralPlan</td><td>Null</td></tr></table></body></html>]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#PolyStyle00</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry>
      <Polygon>
        <extrude>0</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates> 32.394743,35.040539,0.000000 
32.394946,35.040474,0.000000 32.395228,35.040376,0.000000 
32.395274,35.040366,0.000000 32.395306,35.040379,0.000000 
32.395318,35.040406,0.000000 32.395308,35.040847,0.000000 
32.394855,35.040830,0.000000 32.394861,35.040659,0.000000 
32.394642,35.040669,0.000000 32.394506,35.040674,0.000000 
32.394505,35.040673,0.000000 32.394505,35.040672,0.000000 
32.394505,35.040671,0.000000 32.394504,35.040670,0.000000 
32.394504,35.040669,0.000000 32.394504,35.040668,0.000000 
32.394503,35.040667,0.000000 32.394503,35.040666,0.000000 
32.394503,35.040666,0.000000 32.394503,35.040665,0.000000 
32.394502,35.040664,0.000000 32.394502,35.040663,0.000000 
32.394502,35.040662,0.000000 32.394502,35.040661,0.000000 
32.394502,35.040660,0.000000 32.394502,35.040659,0.000000 
32.394501,35.040658,0.000000 32.394501,35.040657,0.000000 
32.394501,35.040656,0.000000 32.394501,35.040655,0.000000 
32.394501,35.040654,0.000000 32.394501,35.040653,0.000000 
32.394501,35.040652,0.000000 32.394501,35.040651,0.000000 
32.394501,35.040650,0.000000 32.394501,35.040649,0.000000 
32.394502,35.040649,0.000000 32.394502,35.040648,0.000000 
32.394502,35.040647,0.000000 32.394502,35.040646,0.000000 
32.394502,35.040645,0.000000 32.394502,35.040644,0.000000 
32.394503,35.040643,0.000000 32.394503,35.040642,0.000000 
32.394503,35.040641,0.000000 32.394503,35.040640,0.000000 
32.394504,35.040639,0.000000 32.394504,35.040638,0.000000 
32.394504,35.040637,0.000000 32.394505,35.040636,0.000000 
32.394505,35.040636,0.000000 32.394505,35.040635,0.000000 
32.394506,35.040634,0.000000 32.394506,35.040633,0.000000 
32.394507,35.040632,0.000000 32.394507,35.040631,0.000000 
32.394508,35.040630,0.000000 32.394508,35.040629,0.000000 
32.394509,35.040629,0.000000 32.394509,35.040628,0.000000 
32.394510,35.040627,0.000000 32.394510,35.040626,0.000000 
32.394511,35.040625,0.000000 32.394512,35.040624,0.000000 
32.394512,35.040624,0.000000 32.394513,35.040623,0.000000 
32.394514,35.040622,0.000000 32.394514,35.040621,0.000000 
32.394515,35.040621,0.000000 32.394516,35.040620,0.000000 
32.394516,35.040619,0.000000 32.394517,35.040618,0.000000 
32.394518,35.040618,0.000000 32.394519,35.040617,0.000000 
32.394519,35.040616,0.000000 32.394520,35.040616,0.000000 
32.394521,35.040615,0.000000 32.394522,35.040614,0.000000 
32.394523,35.040614,0.000000 32.394524,35.040613,0.000000 
32.394624,35.040579,0.000000 32.394743,35.040539,0.000000</coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
<Style id="PolyStyle00">
  <LabelStyle>
    <color>00000000</color>
    <scale>0.000000</scale>
  </LabelStyle>
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff0000e6</color>
    <width>3.000000</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>00000000</color>
    <outline>1</outline>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize [geoPHP](https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP)

Here is an example

```
$kml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>The Pentagon</name>
    <Polygon>
      <extrude>1</extrude>
      <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
            -77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100 
            -77.05465973756702,38.87291016281703,100 
            -77.05315536854791,38.87053267794386,100 
            -77.05552622493516,38.868757801256,100 
            -77.05844056290393,38.86996206506943,100 
            -77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
      <innerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
            -77.05668055019126,38.87154239798456,100 
            -77.05542625960818,38.87167890344077,100 
            -77.05485125901024,38.87076535397792,100 
            -77.05577677433152,38.87008686581446,100 
            -77.05691162017543,38.87054446963351,100 
            -77.05668055019126,38.87154239798456,100
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </innerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
</kml>';

$polygon = geoPHP::load($kml, 'kml');

$centroid = $polygon->getCentroid();

$centX = $centroid->getX();

$centY = $centroid->getY();
```